# php oracle retrieve date

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I dunno what im doing wrong but the following code doesnt seem to work for me im just getting null for $username. There is definitely values in the database, and i have connected to this database before and executed queries on it with the exact same code and worked.

Can anyone tell me why this code wont work?

```
  $c = oci_connect('myuser','mypassword','//localhost/xe');

 $id = 1;
 $sql = "SELECT *  FROM USERS WHERE USERID= :id" ;

$stmt = oci_parse($c, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":id",$id);

oci_execute($stmt);
$res =  oci_fetch_array($stmt);

$username = $res["USERNAME"];
echo $username;
```

Comment: The code looks right to me. Are you sure you have an user with id=1?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be looping that array or referring to the first result by the key value...

Comment: hey yea im sure, ive used this code before and worked i just dont know whats going on, ive printed out $res and it had the correct results in i

Comment: Suddenly started working didnt change anything, cheers for the help anyway

Comment: @clonebaby59 - how odd. If indeed no code was changed at all, you should work out what caused that otherwise it might be a problem when in production.

Comment: @Flukey yea it is odd, Started to refer using key value and it worked, then decieded to try it again with the code above and suddenly worked, eh would you have any idea what might have caused it?

Comment: TRY "SELECT *  FROM USERS WHERE USERID= :id AND USERNAME IS NOT NULL".

Answer (score 0):

You probably have one record with NULL username.

try replacing:

```
$res =  oci_fetch_array($stmt);
$username = $res["USERNAME"];
```

with:

```
while($res = oci_fetch_array($stmt))
{
  $username = $res["USERNAME"];
  echo $username;
}
```